# SCP: How to get role collection (CF) and roles (NEO) through the api

Tags: sap-cloud-foundry

I'm working with the SAP cloud platform with Neo and Cloud Foundry Applications/Organizations on it. Currently I have the task to get all role collections from the cloud foundry applications and all the roles (or better called groups) from Neo.

Currently I can access the CF SCP API through the v3 cloud controller and get for example all roles from the cloud foundry applications.

The two problems I'm facing are that:

- I dont know how to get the role collections, because I couldn t find anything in the documentation (I can get the roles but they do not link with the role collection because I think role collections are a SAP thing and not a CF thing).
- I dont know how to access the NEO-API (I never worked with NEO) and I dont know how to get roles/groups from it

Does anybody know how I can do these things and has documentation for me so I can read a little further?